# After prepend, set value as input javascript then process values in php script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using script to print selected values from table into another div.

```
<script>
    $(".addValues").click(function () {
        $('#selection').show();
        var $this = $(this),
        myCol = $this.closest("td"),
        myRow = myCol.closest("tr"),
        targetArea = $("#selection");

        var qte_input = ('<input type="text" name="kolicina" id="kolicina" placeholder="kg / m" size="10"/>');
        var broj = ($("td.data-id", myRow).text());
        targetArea.prepend(broj + qte_input +"<hr />"); 

        var arr = { sifra:broj, kolicina:qte_input };
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'script.php',
            data: arr,
            type: 'post',
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to get selected values in `script.php`, multiple values will be selected and after each selection I need to type quantity that is `var qte_input`.

Could anyone tell me how to set `var broj` as input and in the same time print it to another div as selected?

html code

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>                                  
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>-</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while($r=$q->fetch()){ ?>
      <tr>                                
        <td class='data-id'><?=''. $r['Id']?> </td>                       
        <td> <button class="addValues" value="<?=''. $r['Id']?>"><i class="ion-ios-cart-outline"></button></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Once I click on button one value prints in div. Multiple values could be selected as displayed on the image. Once I finish selection I hit button "Pošalji zahtjev" it should pick up all [image]

Comment: It's seems that you already set `broj` as `input` (If I understand your meaning). If you want to append it to another div, just do: `$('your_div').html(broj)`.

Comment: I am trying to get all values of broj which are selected. They should be in array because multiple selections could be made.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand the problem, Can you add your `html` code? Or even better, create a snippet or bin..

Comment: I have added html code and image. Thank you very much for your time, when I use debugger I get null for var broj

Comment: My pleasure ;) What do you mean by `all values of broj`? I can see (in the html) only one `td.data-id`. Where are the rest of the values?

Comment: I make selections as you can see on the image above. I should get all values from that div and manipulate with them in script.php  As you can see on the image there are 1721, 17254,16227. After each value I should type number. So each value will hold two elements 1721 and one number. Once I hit "Pošalji zahtjev" all values should be processed to script.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102456/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-user3651819).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a function which collect you all data from the table. After that this collection should be sent to you backend via ajax. Demo in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgrem9gb/

```
/**
 *  Function collect the form data
 */
function collectData(container){
    var data = [];
    $(container).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function(index, item){
        var rowData = {
            id: $(item).find('td.data-id').text(),
            value: $(item).find('input[name="kolicina"]').val()
        };
        data.push(rowData);
    });
    return data;
}

/**
 *  Excecute the data collect function and the ajax post
 */
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'script.php',
    data: collectData('#datatable'),
    type: 'post',
});
```